# Keep a letter centered in a textblock

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a speedreader program, like Spirtz (http://spritzinc.com/).

Right now, I'm struggling to figure out how to keep a single character (the red character) in a fixed location, while the word around the character changes lenghts.

The problem is that I have variable fonts, text sizes, window sizes etc. I could make it hardcoded with Margins & TextAlignment, but when I change any of the sizes, it would just break and misalign.

I tried to create three different TextBlocks and aligning them, but as I said, it doesn't really work with dynamic sizes.

Or maybe I'm tackling this issue in a wrong way? Any suggestions?

Comment: Tip: Suppose the word is "apple", where you are focusing on _second_ `p`, ie. "a'p'ple". Then pre-fix or post-fix empty spaces by calculating exact characters left on both side of focussed letter. Resulting in "__a`p`ple". Empty space here is shown using  `_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="leftText" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="centerText" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="Red"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="rightText" Grid.Column="2"/>
</Grid>
```

You may now set any word in code behind like

```
leftText.Text = "Exa";
centerText.Text = "m";
rightText.Text = "ple";
```